# Download all modified files between two versions from GitHub, using GitHub REST-API

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I have two different versions (tags) of the repository, I compared them and got a list of all files which changed between the versions.
Now, I want to download all those files from the two versions, using GitHub REST-API.
How can I do this?

Comment: This is going to be horribly inefficient in the general case.  Is there a reason you can't use a Git clone?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to download the entire repository, only the modified files

Comment: You are actually better off using a shallow clone, which will likely be smaller than a Base64-encoded set of JSON responses, much faster, and won't run into rate limits.